# Getting an empty string as the output of a piped zypper search Linux command while executing it in ruby using backticks or Mixlib::ShellOut

Tags: ruby, linux, pipe, mixlib-shellout

I’m trying to run a piped Linux command in ruby by enclosing it in backticks`` and by using Mixlib::ShellOut. But in both the cases, I'm getting an empty string as the output even though the actual output looks like this 
    i | kernel-default-devel          | package    | 3.0.101-108.21.1 | x86_64 | SLES11-SP4-Updates

Actually, the zypper search command will display the output in a table format.

The command I’m using is
    zypper search -s kernel | grep -P '(^|\s)\Kkernel-default-devel(?=\s|)' | grep (rpm -qa | grep kernel-default-[0-9] | sort -Vr | head -1 | cut -c 16- | awk ‘{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-7)}’)

The code for Mixlib::ShellOut is given below.

```
current_package_cmd = "zypper search -s kernel | grep -P '(^|\s)\Kkernel-default-devel(?=\s|$)' | grep $(rpm -qa | grep kernel-default-[0-9] | sort -Vr | head -1 | cut -c 16- | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-7)}')"
cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(current_package_cmd )
cmd.run_command 
current_package = cmd.stdout
status = cmd.exitstatus
log "current package is #{current_package} and status is #{status}"
```

The value of output variable current_package is empty string and the exitstatus is 1.

Kindly advise how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Since the exit status is 1, your command seems to fail when executed via shellout. Have you checked the stderr output?

Comment: @kaikuchn : The stderr is also empty. This is the code I have added to get the output, exitstatus and error.  
    current_package = cmd.stdout
    current_package_err = cmd.stderr
    status = cmd.exitstatus
    log "current package is #{current_package} and status is #{status} and error is #{current_package_err} package version is #{package_version}"

And this is the output while chef run
 log[current package is  and status is 1 and error is  package version is 3.0.101-108.21.1] action write

Comment: Here's one more thing to try: prefix your command with `set -x;` to make the shell echo commands with expanded variables to stdout.. Then you could check if anything is amiss.